# asp,.net session how keep session live long time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i don't know where is problem ?? i need to keep current session keep live till client logout but i tried a lot and all solutions doesn't make a sense and in every webpage i should check in Page_load if session still have value or not by

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Postion"] as string))
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

to prevent website crashing . so if i remove this line from all pages i will get this

[image: this screenshot problem]

also it should redirect to Login.aspx page based on webconfig but the same issue exist and here is Web.Config file

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
        <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="resources" type="DevExpress.Web.ResourcesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Dashboard.v17.1.Web, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Dashboard.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.DataAccess.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Office.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.PivotGrid.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.Resources.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Charts.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Xpo.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Pdf.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.Bootstrap.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/></assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MyAuth" timeout="7000000" protection="All" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <pages validateRequest="false">
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="DropDownListChosen" namespace="DropDownListChosen"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=167.114.12.244;Initial Catalog=Wash;Integrated Security=False;User ID=BeljWash;Password=A100310021001a;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;user instance=False " name="ConnectionString"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<devExpress>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies="" baseColor="" font=""/>
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true"/>
    <settings accessibilityCompliant="false" bootstrapMode="Bootstrap3" doctypeMode="Html5" rightToLeft="false" checkReferencesToExternalScripts="true" protectControlState="true" ieCompatibilityVersion="edge"/>
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl=""/>
</devExpress>
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully.

Comment: it's said no value in session !!!

Comment: Are you sure `Position` is not null?

Comment: yes i fill value from login page and this message appear after 3 or 4 minutes of stop using the website

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the timeout to your sessions ! use something like this

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

where 20 is minutes !
session wont expire before 20 minutes or until you made them null from Code Behind ! 
Thanks :)

Comment: This is only true if you use an [out of process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) mode, due to the fact that an app pool recycle can reset in process session state early.

Comment: set to 1400 but expire after some minutes

Comment: Can you tell me how can i keep session live in webconfig , Example please

Comment: definetly it will be because when you close the application and then rerun your code it starts from the begining !

Comment: try to wait on running code session wont expire till the time you mention